# consumir servicio Restful en php

Tags: php, webservice, rest

estoy tratando de consumir un servicio Restful pero me envia un error el cual no conosco por que no reconoce los parametros adjunto mi codigo y la respuesta del error

```html
$dat=array(
        'entidad' => "F001",'tipoIdentificacion' => 'CC','numeroIdentificacion' => '1020442757'
    );


$postdata =http_build_query( $dat );
    
//print_r($postdata);


$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);




$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
//var_dump($context);
$result=file_get_contents('http://172.18.131.195:9090/lince/rest/pazysalvo1/avaldescfin',FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH, $context);
//echo $result;
//$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://172.18.131.195:9090/lince/rest/pazysalvo1/avaldescfin?', false, $context),true);

print_r($result);
```

No reconoce los parametros que estoy enviando y me devuelve vacio

```
{"entidad":"F001","tipoIdentificacion":null,"numeroIdentificacion":null,"codPersona":0,"estadoConsulta":"1","avales":[]}
```

como debo enviar los parametros?
que debo corregir en el codigo?

Comment: Creo que podrías añadir algunas cosas adicionales para que podamos ayudar de mejor manera, por ejemplo el código de **avaldescfin** para que podamos ver donde recibes los parámetros

Comment: Tienes que preguntar al desarrollador del servicio sobre la forma en que debes consultarlo, en eso solamente puede ayudarte quien programó el servicio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

de este modo no me dio el resultado así que probé de otra forma y si me funciono acá dejo la solución.

```html
//set POST variables
$url = 'http://172.18.131.195:9090/lince/rest/pazysalvo1/avaldescfin';
$fields = array(
        'entidad' => 'F001','tipoIdentificacion' =>$tipoid,'numeroIdentificacion' => $numid
    );

//url-ify the data for the POST
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) 
{ 
    $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
}
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);


//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);

$result=json_decode($result,true);

/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas otro header para la longitud del contenido. 
Para un *contexto de flujo* el `header` lo puedes establecer de dos maneras:

1. Como **cadena**, donde cada header debe terminar con `\r\n`
2. Como **arreglo**, cada header es un elemento del arreglo; sin índice/clave y sin separador de línea:

```
$opts = array('http' => array( 'method'  => 'POST'
                             , 'header'  => array( 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                                                 , 'Content-Length: '.strlen($postdata)
                                                 )
                             , 'content' => $postdata
                             )
             );
```

Comment: Ya lo intenten y siguen sin dar respuesta el servicio.